# Reusing a customized style in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, datagrid, controltemplate

By modifying the `RowStyle` of a `DataGrid` I have created a customized grid that will display some buttons at the end of the row when the mouse hovers above the row:

[image: Custom DataGrid]

I created a new style for `DataGridRow` based on the default style. I then modified the XAML to add my buttons inside a `StackPanel` (details omitted):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyle" TargetType="swcd:DataGridRow">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="swcd:DataGridRow">
          ...
          <StackPanel x:Name="RowControlsPanel">
            <Button>
              ... these are the buttons displayed on the row
```

The `DataGrid` is modified using the style:

```
<swcd:DataGrid RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}">
  ...
</swcd:DataGrid>
```

I want to create another grid in a similar manner, but with a different set of buttons at the end of the row. I could create a textual copy of my style and modify it accordingly, but I was hoping that I could create a proper reusable class. I'm not sure how to approach this since the stuff I want to factor out of my style is a collection of controls (buttons) inside a style.

My approach so far is to create a `MyDataGrid` class derived from `DataGrid`. I have added a new property `RowControls` to `MyDataGrid` enabling me to instantiate it like this:

```
<local:MyDataGrid>
  <local:MyDataGrid.RowControls>
    <Button>
       ... these controls should go at the end of the row
  </local:MyDataGrid.RowControls>
  ...
</local:MyDataGrid>
```

`MyDataGrid` uses a `RowStyle` as described above. But how do the contents of the `MyDataGrid.RowControls` collection get into the `Content` of `RowControlsPanel` in the style? I think I should do that in `OnApplyTemplate` of the `DataGridRow`, but then I need to derive a new `MyDataGridRow` class from `DataGridRow`. Unfortunately it seems that `DataGrid` is hardcoded to use `DataGridRow` and I'm not able to inject my own derived row class. I get the feeling that I need to approach my problem of reuse in a different manner, but I'm not sure how?

Customizing simple controls like buttons by adding new properties and modifying the control template is quite easy, but how do I customize a complex control like `DataGrid` where the template I need to customize is nested inside the grid?

Comment: Any reason why it can't just be a column? You can hide the lines so it would look exactly as you have there by overriding the headerstyle and cellstyle. Row mouseover'll be your only problem and I think that could be handled with an attached property or a behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a reusable class you might consider reusing your style with a Silverlight 3 BasedOn style:

[http://community.irritatedvowel.com/blogs/pete_browns_blog/archive/2009/03/18/Silverlight-3-*1320*-BasedOn-Styles.aspx](http://community.irritatedvowel.com/blogs/pete_browns_blog/archive/2009/03/18/Silverlight-3-_1320_-BasedOn-Styles.aspx)

That technique will allow you to make minor modifications, like changing the row buttons in your example, to an existing style.

Comment: That was exactly the kind of feedback I was looking for. Unfortunately `BasedOn` only allows med to inherit things like property setters from parent styles. In my case I want to parametrize a single property (the `Template`) with values from a property on a visual parent.

Comment: Good point, I see why BasedOn isn't what you're looking for... and I flat can't figure out better way!  Maybe you'll get lucky and a Xaml expert will post something elegant *ahem* Jeff Wilcox *ahem*